# C# - PowerShell object execute Remove-AppxPackage successfully but unable to remove application from another user

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to remove the application from another user account (Specific selected user)
I used below query
Remove-AppxPackage -Package FACEBOOK.FACEBOOK_2021.927.1.0_neutral__8xx8rvfyw5nnt -User S-1-5-21-1982064058-2852822003-722279830-1009

Format
Remove-AppxPackage -Package (PackageFullName) -User (User.SID)

above query work on login user but not working for other users

Comment: And the documentation you're following says this should work? Or are you not following documentation? It seems pretty obvious what the problem is, they don't allow you to remove apps from another account you're not logged in as

Comment: Try running powershell as administrator

Comment: I am using window 11 
@JeremyThompson document allowing the same

Comment: @MindSwipe I am running PowerShell as admin

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2022-ps

I am using above link for same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below script format work for me

Get-AppxPackage -User SID | Where PackageFullName -eq packagefullname | Remove-AppxPackage -User

### script

Get-AppxPackage -User S-1-5-21-1982064058-2852822003-722279830-1009 | Where PackageFullName -eq FACEBOOK.FACEBOOK_2021.927.1.0_neutral__8xx8rvfyw5nnt | Remove-AppxPackage -User S-1-5-21-1982064058-2852822003-722279830-1009

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the '-Force' option?

Comment: Have no idea about this can you please tell me how we used this option ?